# Copy/paste between Access and Excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

in one of my form in Access, i want to put together some texts in a string, then my user can copy this string into Excel, in different columns.
For example, there are 5 letters in my form: A B C D E, when the users hit a button "copy", then do the paste in Excel, say in the case A1. Then the 5 letters will be pasted into 5 columns in one row:

A1  B1  C1  D1  E1

A   B   C   D   E

What i am searching is whether there is a symbol just to indicate the end of a column.

Comment: Have you tried "paste special" in excel?  That might work out of the box.

Comment: @Mikecito: "Paste special" (or the text import wizard) will surely work, but adding tabs before pasting will make handling for the user a little bit easier.

Comment: @the one who asked to close this: This is indeed a programming question, see my comment to Brian Willis answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use tabs between each value, and Excel will break the data up into columns when it's pasted in.

Comment: +1. To make this a complete solution, one needs to add those tabs between the values. If the user should not do this manually, one will have, for example, replace the spaces by tabs (using VBA) and copy the resulting string to the clipboard programmatically. Look here http://word.mvps.org/faqs/macrosvba/ManipulateClipboard.htm how to do this.

Comment: Then how can i access the clipboard using vba in ACCESS? The link is for ms-word and there isn't a DataObject in Access ...

Comment: @darkjh That can be complicated depending on which version of Access you're using. I suggest submitting a new question on Stack Overflow about this problem.

Comment: @darkjh: it works in Access the same way as in Word - you just have to add a reference to MS Forms 2.0 lib. This lib may not be listed in the box when you go to "Tools/References", but you can add it by manually adding a reference to `FM20.dll` from the Windows system32 directory.